# How to use Realm in a library

Tags: android, module, realm, kotlin, android-library

i'm trying to understand how to use Realm in a library that i'm making, i now understand RealmModules after a couple of days of research (if someone from Realm reads this, you should really improve on documentation about use in libraries). I've made a simple class that gives me the realm with library configuration:

```
object ChatRealm {
    fun getChatRealm(): Realm{
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                .name("mtchat_realmDB")
                .schemaVersion(2)
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .modules(ChatModule())
                .build()
        return Realm.getInstance(config)
    }
}
```

the module is this

```
@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
class ChatModule {}
```

and in the project Application class i setup realm like this

```
class App: Application() {
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        initRealm()
        setupRealm()
    }

    private fun initRealm() {
        Realm.init(this)
    }

    private fun setupRealm(){
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(
                RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                        .modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), ChatModule())
                        .build()
        )
    }
}
```

Now the trouble i'm having is that the build is failing or the app is crashing for various reasons based on how i configure the gradle files.

My :app gradle is this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary= true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.2'
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile project(':mtchat')
}
```

and my library gradle is this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$compat_version"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$compat_version"
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$compat_version"
    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$compat_version"
    compile "com.android.support:design:$compat_version"
    compile "de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0"
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
}
```

and this is my project gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.4-3'
    ext.compat_version = '26.0.2'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.7.2"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and based on if i add or not the apply plugin: 'realm-android' to the :app module i get either RealmObject "X" is not part of the schema for this realm or if i add the plugin to the app gradle it fails to build the project completely.

**Is there anyone that has used Realm in a library and wants to explain how, clearly and in depth, maybe this could be used as future reference**

EDIT: With the above configuration i get this error when building

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/realm/ChatRealmProxyInterface;
```

EDIT 2:

I managed to get it working by defining modules for both app and library and avoiding naming the realm models in the app the same as the ones in the library ( is this required? Or is there a way to isolate the library models so that the user can use the same names that the library models use?) Still this took me 2 days of research and i'm still unsure if I'm doing it right. It would be REALLY great if someone with more knowledge than me made a nice tutorial or something.

Comment: `(if someone from Realm reads this, you should really improve on documentation about use in libraries)` there is [an official example for it.](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/8a3c4ce1f0d47c64dc4d97cfafbea1d65f5e5827/examples/moduleExample)

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Yes i read it and it clarifies some things but there is no documentation that really explains the rules of using realm in a library, like if you have to include the "apply plugin" in the :app gradle if you already have it in the library, if the library user can use RealmObjects with the same name as the ones in the library and in depth stuff like that.

Comment: Realm do not take package names into account for modules and model classes, so yes, having the same name in the library and app will create conflicts. We did try to document the restrictions around schemas in the docs https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#schemas as well as having the example project linked above, but it sounds like we need to describe the restrictions in the docs better.

Comment: Ah thank you, i thought i was doing something very wrong

Answer (score 2):

you are facing Over 64K Methods Multiple dex file problem not related to realm library you need to add dependencies

Configure your app for multidex

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    productFlavors {
        dev {
            // Enable pre-dexing to produce an APK that can be tested on
            // Android 5.0+ without the time-consuming DEX build processes.
            minSdkVersion 21
        }
        prod {
            // The actual minSdkVersion for the production version.
            minSdkVersion 14
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                                                 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

If you do not override the Application class, edit your manifest file to set android:name in the  tag as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">
    <application
            android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" >
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If you do override the Application class, change it to extend MultiDexApplication (if possible) as follows:

```
public class MyApplication extends SomeOtherApplication {
  @Override
  protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
     super.attachBaseContext(base);
     MultiDex.install(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but that wasn't the problem, the dex error went away with a clean build, it was a configuration problem with modules and Model names

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your project gradle file

```
dependencies {
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:3.5.0"
}
```

Comment: It's already there, sorry i forgot to write it, i'll update the question